# Get password after MSAL authentication

Tags: angular, .net-core, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

Is there any way to get the password after msal authentication using username and password.
Neither ClaimsPrincipal contains any password info nor the token which we receive after successful authentication from azure ad, authenticating using angular MsalService.

Please help..

Comment: You need to check how MSAL works first, check this image for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/media/active-directory-develop-guidedsetup-javascriptspa-introduction/javascriptspa-intro.svg